# Avoid duplicating code

Tags: c, c99

let's say I have:

```
  switch( choice ) {
  case A:   
     stmt;
     do_stmt_related2A;
  break;

  case B:
     stmt;
     do_stmt_related2B;
  break;

  case C: something_different();
   ...
  }
```

How could I avoid duplicating stmt code?

But is there any workaround?
gcc extension label as value looks quite good for such situation.

```
   switch( choice ) {
     do {
     case A:  ptr = &&A_label;
     break;
     case B:  ptr = &&B_label;
     } while(0);
              stmt;
              goto *ptr;
     case C: ...
```

Is there any trick that can do the same in ANSI-C?
Edit: Of course I have thought of function/macro/inline. But anything else?
It's not about performance either. Just for educational purpose. ;)

Comment: Can't imagine that the sniplet you posted for a `gcc' variant would compile. Please post only valid code that your compiler has ack'd.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt, it's gcc extension.

Comment: @Nyan: I didn't mean the address of pointer stuff, I knew about that extension. I meant the do while thingy. To my complete surprise I have to learn that this is a valid C construct, know as Duff's device. I am baffled. Never finished learning.

Comment: Why wouldn't compile? It's a simple duff's device. Very important performance optimization in C.

Comment: "Simple" and "important" should not be spoken in the same breath as "Duff's Device".  It's an ugly, unintuitive construct with questionable benefit, even for the purpose of optimization.  It's a neat trick and an interesting historical note, but its use in new code should be strongly discouraged.

Comment: _Actively_ discouraged. As in "people using it should be beaten to death with a stick of wet celery (to make the pain last longer)". There is _no_ place in modern code for Duff's device and it ilk. Check wikipedia for some quick snippets: "in some cases two loops may actually be faster", "When numerous instances of Duff's device were removed from the XFree86 Server in version 4.0, there was an improvement in performance", "may also interfere with pipelining and branch prediction on some architectures".

Answer (score 29):

Why don't you just refactor `stmt` (I'm assuming this is a big chunk of instructions rather than a single line) into its own function `do_stmt()` and call it? Something like:

```
switch( choice ) {
    case A:
        do_stmt();
        do_stmt_related2A;
        break;
    case B:
        do_stmt();
        do_stmt_related2B;
        break;
    case C: something_different();
        ...
}
```

That gcc trick is truly hideous. I would rather have readable code over such monstrosities any day.

You should always assume that the programmer that inherits your code is a homicidal maniac who knows where you live :-)

Comment: +1 falling in love with monstrous syntax like that is a surefire way to self-destruction.

Answer (score 17):

> How could I avoid duplicating stmt code?

By putting it into a function and call that.

And, no, you do ***not*** know whether this will slow down your application until you profiled it and found it to be the bottleneck. (And in case it really is, use a macro or, if that's C99, make the function `inline`.)

Comment: When you down-vote something for the first few times, a hint appears, asking you to explain in a comment why you down-voted. After a while, that hint doesn't appear anymore. However, you still should explain why you down-voted an answer. __So why was this down-voted?__

Comment: This looks really useful to me. Anyone who thinks otherwise is either an idiot or troll. +1 for good answer, and if I could give you a sympathy +2 I would.

Comment: @sbi LOL;started sort-of flame question on meta.SO 'cause of this (people misusing the downvote),&I am amazed a 23k rep user pretends explanation,when other users on meta.SO appassionately affirmed and stressed the freedom to downvote without giving a reason!I tried to explain indiretly that it is about principles,not numbers (reputation);but likely none believed me and they considered me "bitching and moaning",instead of going on and ignore downvotes, since however the "system",if your answer is good someway, will adjust everything. Worked for you (+8-1), not so good for me. Rep matters.

Comment: and moreover, @Platinum Azure, according to the very same people of my prev comment, calling someone idiot since we disagree with him on usefulness of an answer is a no-no-no... usefulness is highly subjective, and so the correctness of an answer! So it is on SO! ... So, virtual -1 for the rep power, +2 for both empathy about convincement downvoters should (must, I say) explain, and since the answer is ok, after all (even though it is the most obvious thing to do)

Comment: @ShinTakezou It seemed to me like the downvoter might have been the question asker, given his snarky reply. Asking a question and then downvoting the right answers strikes me as trolling.

Comment: @Platinum Azure but the system allows for it;I would suggest that who makes the question,can only accept the "right" one but not upvote or downvote.But I won't try to suggest it as new feature... noticed people are very closed minded,sospicious to changes, and even more if an idea comes because of a received downvote, so I won't try anymore to make this place a better,rather I will limit myself in commenting (a lot!) and trying to help people needing helps,and if they don't like my efforts, ... I have a personal black list of users that won't see my answers to their questions anymore!

Comment: @ShinTakezou & @Platinum: The reason I made that comment is that I want to understand what is wrong with my answer. Yes, the answer was short and it states what seems to be the obvious. But the obvious has to be said, too, and I do believe that it is the right answer. I'm the first to defend the right of others to disagree with me, but I'd love to know _what_ they disagree about. Oh, and I took Nyan's comment as sympathizing with me. ICBWT.

Comment: I am totally with you, @sbi.I would like to be forced to explain why when downvoting. But many people are not happy with this duty; they are scared by possible retaliations, and reputation becomes more important than other things. I made a Q with a proposal in meta.SO. Q closed as duplicate (it was not an exact duplicate), and started a sort of "flame comments war" to defend my idea (which I do not pretend to be perfect and defendible forever,but I will do because of how biased,unpropositive,superficial,badly motivated was the initial feedback).Enough of that.So ur comment made me laugh!:D

Comment: A simple +1 vs -1 is never as educational as "-1 because ...". Encouraging the desired behaviour can be much faster with comments.

Comment: I'd reason the following: "And, no, you do not know whether this will slow down your application until you profiled it and found it to be the bottleneck" == more preaching == heard it all before == yawn == -1. No it was not me who downvoted.

Comment: This answer is not very useful if `stmt` depends on a lot of local variables. Even if you can make it an inline function, passing pointers to all the variables it needs, and even if the pointers get optimized out, the code will still be hideously ugly with everything converted to pointers.

Comment: @R..: Of course, repeating the code isn't half as ugly, right?

Comment: Repeating the code is ugly, but plenty of other people have provided answers that avoid both problems - for example the `if (choice == A || choice == B)` prior to the switch, or putting `case A:` and `case B:` on consecutive lines followed by `stmt;` and `if (choice == A) { ... } else { ... }`

Comment: @R..: But that's just repeating the condition. Sorry, but I utterly fail to see how this is less ugly than passing a few parameters to a function.

Answer (score 9):

Aside from the common sentiment to refactor the common code into a sub-function, the simplest way to refactor your code using standard C functionality is probably:

```
if (choice == A || choice == B) {
    stmt;
}

switch( choice ) {
  case A:   
    do_stmt_related2A;
    break;

  case B:
    do_stmt_related2B;
    break;

  case C:
    something_different();
    ...
}
```

It cleanly expresses what you want to do, and it avoids the switch-inside-a-switch that prevents some compilers from optimizing the code effectively.

Answer (score 4):

There will be *some* code either way - you can have duplicated code, or code to avoid duplication. So I'm curious as to how complex the `stmt;` code really is.

The simple, clean solution is to move the shared part (`stmt`) into a seperate function.

```
void do_shared_stmt(void) {
 stmt;
}
/* .... */
swtich(choise) {
case A:
  do_shared_stmt();
  do_stmt_related2A();
  break;
case B:
  do_shared_stmt();
  do_stmt_related2B();
  break;
case C:
  something_different();
/* ... */
}
```

Another solution (that might be acceptable, depending on your situation) is to nest branching statements:

```
swtich(choise) {
case A:
case B:
  stmt;
  if(choise == A) {
    do_stmt_related2A();
  } else {̈́
    do_stmt_related2B();
  }
  break;
case C:
  something_different();
/* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll probably do something like that :

```
void do_stmt(int choice)
{
    stmt;
    switch(choice)
    {
         case A:
             do_stmt_related2A;
             break;
         case B:
             do_stmt_related2B;
             break;
    }  
}
/* ... */
switch(choice)
{
    case A:
    case B:
        do_stmt(choice);
        break;
    case C:
         something_different();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for something like what I append here. Sure, you probably had the idea yourself to have a nested switch statement, nothing new. What this does in addition is that it evaluates `choice` only once.

It also avoids the gcc construct of addresses of labels, so there is no indirection, here. A decent compiler should be able to optimize such a thing quite well.

Observe also, that `my_choice` is an `intmax_t` so this should be compatible with any type `choice` could have.

(Putting in the `for` is just for the fun, and would only work with C99, obviously. You could replace it with an extra {} around the stuff and just a declaration of `my_choice` for C89.)

```
typedef enum { one = 1, two, three } number;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  number choice = (number)argc;

  for (intmax_t _0 = 0, my_choice = choice; !_0; ++_0)
    switch(my_choice) {
    case one:;
    case two:;
      {
        printf("Do whatever you want here\n");
        switch (my_choice) {
        case one:
          printf("test 1\n");
          break;
        case two:
          printf("test 2\n");
          break;
        }
        printf("end special\n");
      }
      break;
    default:;
      printf("test %d, default\n", choice);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using goto pointers will likely result in slower code because it shuts off some of gcc's other optimizations (or would the last time I read up on it).  Gcc essentially decides that it could be way too complicated to try to keep up with what might be going on and assumes that many more branch instructions can target every goto label that has been && than is really the case.  If you insist on trying to use this method I suggest that you attempt to use an integer and another switch/case rather than the goto.  Gcc will like be able to make sense of that.

Aside from that, for many statements this may not be worth the work or it may actually work better the way it is.  It really does depend a lot on what `stmt` actually is.

Refactoring `stmt` into a `static` function will likely yield good results if `stmt` is indeed expensive or big code.

Another thing you might try if you can would be to hoist `stmt` out of the switch/case and just execute always execute it.  Sometimes this is the cheapest way to go, but that really does depend on what `stmt` actually does.

Another thing you might do is refactor all of `stmt` ,  `do_stmt_related2A`
, and  `do_stmt_related2A` all into file `static` functions, like this:

```
// args in this is just a psudocode place holder for whatever arguments are needed, and 
// not valide C code.
static void stmt_f(void (*continuation)(arg_list), args) {
   stmt; // This corresponds almost exactly to stmt in your code
   continuation(args);
}
static void do_stmt_related2A_f(args) {
    do_stmt_related2A;
}
static void do_stmp_related2B_f(args) {
    do_stmt_related2B;
}

...
    switch (condition) {
       case A:
          stmt_f(do_stmt_related2A_f, args);
          break;
       case B:
    ...
```

The call to the continuation function at the end of stmt_f is a tail call and will most likely become a jump rather than a real call.  Because all of these are static it is possible that the compiler would see the entire set of values which could be continuation functions and optimize some more, but I don't know that.

Unless stmt is very big it is very likely that this is a micro-optimization that just isn't worth it.  If you really want to know then you should compile to assembly and try to see what the compiler really does with your original code.  It may very well do a better job than you think on it.

Oh, one last thing you might try is if you control what actual values A, B, C.. can take then you could make sure that the ones with similar prefixes have adjacent values.  If A and B really are next to each other and if the compiler decides that it needs to break up the switch/case into a few different jump tables then it will likely put A and B in the same jump table and also see that they have the same prefix and hoist that code out for you.  This is more likely if C, which does not share that prefix, is not adjacent to A or B, but then your overall code could be worse.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need two control structures.  One for dictating execution of the first order instructions, a second for the second order instructions.

```
switch (state) {
    case A:
    case B:
        stmt;

        switch (state) {
            case A:
                do_stmt_related2A;
                break;
            case B:
                do_stmt_related2B;
                break;
        }

        break;

    case C:
        something_different();
        ...
}
```

It's also worth noting that `switch` is less suitable for the second order control structure, you likely want to use a more traditional conditional branch.  Lastly, the real answer to your question regarding goto-label-pointer is that this is what subroutine linkage is for.  If your instructions are *more complex* than a single expression, then you can and should use a function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one alternate to function calls or secondary switch statements:

```
isA=false;
switch( choice ) { 
  case A:    
    isA=true;
  //nobreak
  case B: 
    stmt; 
    isA ? do_stmt_related2A : do_stmt_related2B;
  break; 
  case C: 
    something_different(); 
  break;
}
```

However, I can't say I really recommend it as a coding style.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using gcc, one option is **[nested functions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html)**. These are functions that have access to all the variables of the parent function.

For example:

```
void foo(int bar) {

    int x = 0;
    void stmt(void) { //nested function!!
        x++;
        if (x == 8) {
            x = 0;
        }
    }

    switch( bar ) {
    case A:   
        stmt();
        do_stmt_related2A;
    break;

    case B:
        stmt();
        do_stmt_related2B;
    break;

    case C:
        something_different();
        ...
    break;
    }
}
```

Since this is a gcc extension, it should obviously not be used for code intended to be portable. But it can be fun to play with :) and in certain circumstances makes the code much more readable.

If you have an executable stack you can even create a pointer to a nested function. It's a lot like a lambda function, except horrible - or horribly fun, depending on your perspective. (Like all pointers to "local" objects, the pointer becomes invalid when the parent function exits! Beware!)

Answer (score 0):

Go back to the original meanings of the different case-values.  What do cases A, B and C represent?  If A and B should execute partially the same code, they should have some similarities.  Find them and express them in another way.

The following example makes this clearer.  Suppose that A, B and C are 3 different kinds of animals, and the duplicated code for A and B is actually typical for animals that can fly.  You could then write your code like this:

```
if (can_fly(choice))
   {
   stmt;
   }

switch( choice )
  {
  case A:   
     do_stmt_related2A;
     break;
  case B:
     do_stmt_related2B;
     break;
  case C:
     something_different();
     break;
  }
```

That way, if a 3rd choice D is added later to your application, the chances of forgetting the "stmt" duplicated code is slightly smaller.

If you really want to prevent a function call (to can_fly), and A, B and C are numerical constants, you could make use of bitmasks.  In this example, we use one bit to indicate the animal can fly:

```
if (choice & BIT_CAN_FLY)
   {
   stmt;
   }

switch( choice )
  {
  case A:   
     do_stmt_related2A;
     break;
  case B:
     do_stmt_related2B;
     break;
  case C:
     something_different();
     break;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily just put your `stmt` code into a function and call that function from your case or wherever, you can call a function how ever many times you want.

Answer (score 0):

i see only two possible arrangements of ur logic.

```
L1:
 val
 |
 |-------------------
 |        |         |
 A        B         C
 |        |         |
 stmt     stmt      crap
 |        |
 Afunk    Bfunk

L2:
 val
 |
 |-------------------
 stmt               |
 |---------         |
 |        |         |
 A        B         C
 |        |         |
 Afunk    Bfunk     crap
```

In L1, use inline function for stmt or use L2 if branching twice is ok. If you are talkin about src code duplication(as opposed to duplication in the binary), just inline func will solve ur problem.

Answer (score 0):

Others have already given this answer, but I wanted to state it in formal terms.

If performance isn't your concern, then you've correctly identified one of the typical "code smells" which is [duplicate code](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DuplicatedCode).

One of the most basic refactorings is called [Extract Method](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html). Learn it, live it, love it. The process of identifying duplicate code and eliminating it should be part of your minute-by-minute workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possibility that you should probably ignore (but that's kind of interesting):

```
// function pointer to B function
void (*func)(void) = do_stmt_related2B;
switch(choice) {
case A:
    func = do_stmt_related2A; // change function pointer to A function
case B:
    stmt;
    func(); // call function pointer
    break;

case C:
    something_different();
    ...
}
```

May or may not be more efficient/smaller/readable/advisable/fun than the other solutions. Just an interesting way to tackle this problem that no one else has mentioned.